# Cannot get option to paste text. All I get is the magnifier

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone 5S, I use to be able to long press and select paste (to paste copied text) but now I just get a magnifier instead, I have tried to reset all my settings but still get magnifier.

Comment: are you sure there's something to copy ? Which app are you trying it in ?

Comment: Ah it was the copy that didn't work, thank you.